# Constructing a bijection between $\{1,...,2^n\}$ and $P(\{1,...,n\})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone construct a bijective map from the set $\{1,...,2^n\}$ to the power set $P(\{1,...,n\})$. I'm having trouble thinking of anything easily computable.

Comment: Think about bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $A \in P(\{1, \cdots, n\}) $, attribute $0$ to $x $ if $x \not\in A $, attribute a $1$ to $x $ if $x \in A $.

Using these attributions, can you build a unique identifier for $A $? Maybe using base 2?

Comment: Thanks this is great. It transforms the problem into constructing a permutation of {1,...,2^n}

Comment: @BenScott I think it can be made even simpler. Are you familiar with base 2?

Comment: Yeah I am, I'm using this map in a for a maths program I'm writing

Answer (score 0):

$f:\{1,\dots,2^n\}\to\mathbb{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})$

$f(x)=\{k\mid\text{the $k$th bit in the binary representation of $x$ is $1$}\}$

---

$g:\mathbb{P}(\{1,\dots,n\})\to\{1,\dots,2^n\}$

$g(x)=1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{|x|}2^{x_k-1}$

Comment: What did you mean by x<sub>k</sub>?

Comment: Also I don't see how g can be a bijection if 1 is not mapped to

Comment: @BenScott: if $x=\emptyset$ then $|x|=0$ hence $g(x)=1$.

Comment: @BenScott: If by "x<sub>k</sub>" you meant to ask what is $x_k$, then it is the $k$th element in set $x$.